# How to filter an array based on the true/false value of the object properties inside the array

Tags: arrays, filter, liquid

I am trying to take an array that contains a list of people, and create a new array out of it. I would like the new array to contain only the people that have "true" for one of their properties. So it would look something like this.

```
{% for adult in household.adults %}
    {% unless adult.inactive == true %}
        {% assign active_adults = adult %}
    {% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
```

So I'm basically taking one array, filtering out the objects that have a certain property set to True, and making a new array out of only those objects. I hope that makes sense. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert but as far as I know you can do something like this in Ruby to filter an array:

`household.adults.select {|adult| adult.inactive != true}`

and it returns a new array with only matching elements.

I think you can use Ruby in the Liquid template language?

Link to the API doc: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select